# Close modal but let promise be resolved in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-apps-script, promise

I am using React to write code for my Apps script add-on. I want `handleCancel` to be executed on click of the Cancel button. It executes `someAsyncMethod` and then closes the modal using `google.script.host.close()`.

```
export const SampleCmp = () => {
    const handleCancel = async () => {
        await someAsyncMethod();
        google.script.host.close();
    };

    return (
      <button
        onClick={handleCancel}
      >
        Cancel
      </button>
    );
};

const someAsyncMethod() = async() : Promise<SomeObject> => {
};
```

### Problem

`someAsyncMethod` takes too long (~5s) to execute and I want the modal to close immediately. If I remove the `await` keyword then `someAsyncMethod` does not complete with the resolved value or gets suspended, which I suspect happens because of the `google.script.host.close`. Is there a way the `someAsyncMethod` can continue in the background but we are able to close the modal immediately? Thanks.

Comment: What if you call the close first?

Comment: still does not work. Just to add, if I was to add a `console.log` after `google.script.host.close` it would execute, but it seems all pending promises are suspended.

Comment: What does `someAsyncMethod` do?

Comment: It performs an api call and returns a promise

Comment: Api call to the apps script server?

Comment: If  it's  a api call to somewhere else, the server maybe able to do that. Other than that browser `Worker` or service worker is worth experimenting...

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it's not possible to keep running client-side code (JavaScript) when the host (in this case the modal) is closed. You need to consider a different approach, i.e. instead of using a modal you could use a sidebar, keeping it opened until `someAsyncMethod` finish.

Maybe the use a Google Apps Script add-on as a whole solution is a bad idea and you will have to rethink the solution implementation i.e. web app + add-on or as web-browser extension + add-on.

Comment: I added a console.log after `google.script.host.close` and it executed so **all** client-side code is not suspended, but it seems all pending promises are suspended.

Comment: I think that you are missing that `google.script.host.close` is asynchronous and slow.